# Random Number/Frame function in Actionscript 3.0

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript

I had an old piece of code in a Flash Movie that selected a random frame to start the clip. However, the `random()` function has been deprecated since Flash 5 and in ActionScript 3, it's been completely removed. Now I need to update some of the images in the movie but the timeline just skips right through the clips without stopping. Can anyone help me revise the code?

Here is what I had:

```
function randRange(min:Number, max:Number):Number {
    var randomNum:Number = Math.round(Math.random()*(max-min))+min;   
    return randomNum; 
}     
var myFrame; 
myFrame = randRange(2,7); 
gotoAndStop(myFrame);
```

If you'd like to see the existing clip in action you can view it [here](http://www.supplementscanada.com/SC-SportStacks.swf.html).

Comment: Your code in `randRage()` looks fine, your problem is elsewhere.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback Aaron, but as I said the random() function has been removed in ActionScript 3.0 and no longer works.

Comment: Yes, the `random()` global function has been removed, but `Math.random()` is different and it is still there. In other words, `Math.random()` replaces `random()` global function. The code you posted is perfectly valid AS3, and will generate random `myFrame` values between 2 and 7.

Comment: Thank you @Aaron. You are correct the code I posted seems perfectly valid. The problem appears to be the 'gotoAndStop("Stack00#");' on each random keyframe. I'll keep digging. I certainly appreciate your time with this.

Answer (score 0):

First of all i need tell you for random numbers, use this kod:

```
Math.floor(Math.random() * (1 + max - min) + min);
```

If u want to know why, you can look here : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2yICftpoCYg
or this one : http://www.snorkl.tv/2011/02/use-the-proper-function-for-random-numbers-or-else/

These 2 link are same video's.

Most likely your code seem like this :

```
 function randRange(min:Number, max:Number):Number 
 {
    var randomNum:Number = Math.round(Math.random()*(max-min))+min;   
    return randomNum; 
 }     
var myFrame; 
myFrame = randRange(2,7); 
this.gotoAndStop(myFrame);
```

Comment: Thank you Halil that is certainly good to know, however it appears that it isn't possible to export a movie from Flash CC to HTML5 anymore and keep interaction (lots of movie players). So my whole problem in the first place could be a mute point. (I used to use a plugin called Swiffy which is no longer supported in CC)

Comment: Hmm.. I see. Maybe you can find another plugin and use it with CC hope u can find one :)